# Integration and interpolation in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, typeerror, numerical-integration, linear-interpolation

I have been trying to find a way to do this since days.
I have an interpolated graph which I got from the following code:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    u=np.linspace(0.0,2.6,num=i)
    c=np.linspace(0.3, 1.0, num=i)
    
c_list = np.zeros(len(u))

for i in range(len(u)-1):
    c = ((u[i+1]-u)*c[i]+(u-u[i])*c[i+1])/(u[i+1]-u[i])
print (c)
print (u)
plt.plot(u,c)
plt.show()
```

Now, I have two functions which I want to integrate using the obtained values. For that, I initially wrote:

```
n= lambda u:0.176*(np.exp(1/(u*c)))
integrate.quad(n, 0.0, 0.65)
```

But I keep running into type error no matter how I try to integrate this function. I am new to python and any help is appreciated.

edit: this is the error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_85220/2767225254.py in <module>
     15 print (e[1])
     16 n= lambda u:(0.176*(np.exp(1/(u*c))))
---> 17 integrate.quad(n, 0.0, 2.6)
     18 
     19 q= lambda n: n

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    349 
    350     if weight is None:
--> 351         retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
    352                        points)
    353     else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    461     if points is None:
    462         if infbounds == 0:
--> 463             return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    464         else:
    465             return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Edit: These are the functions i want to integrate:
[image]

Comment: Please include the full traceback for your error.

Comment: Included the traceback @ddejohn

Comment: it is quadrature integration using scipy @BarzanHayati

Comment: What is u' and u'' and other ones? Please explain about these parameters. Do you want to somebody helps you to resolve that or you want to confuse us?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this one:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad_vec
import numpy as np

n= lambda u:0.176*(np.exp(1/(u*c)))
y, err = quad_vec(n, 0.0, 0.65)
# integrate.quad(n, 0.0, 0.65)
```

and `y = array([nan, nan, nan, nan, inf])` and `err = nan`

Comment: i need to have one single value after integration.

Comment: Write formula for those function that you want to take integration.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the function n returning an array of values. This is because c is an array. You can see when c is a constant there is no issue. I think the function you should use is `integrate.quad_vec()`.